# Why does Audio not Work in my code unity ? unity c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

For some reason, my code is audio not working only... I have no idea why. can someone help? I am using a `AudioClip[]` my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
public class LevelManage : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject[] animals;
    public GameObject[] blackAnimals;
    Vector3[] animalStartPos;
    Vector3[] animalBlackStartPos;

    public AudioSource source;
    public AudioClip[] Correct;
    public AudioClip InCorrect;
    void Start()
    {
        animalStartPos = new Vector3[animals.Length];
        animalBlackStartPos = new Vector3[blackAnimals.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < animals.Length; i++)
        {
            animalStartPos[i] = animals[i].transform.position;
            animalBlackStartPos[i] = blackAnimals[i].transform.position;
        }
    }

    //drag

    public void dragAnimal(GameObject animal)
    {
        animal.transform.position = Input.mousePosition;
    }

    //drop

    public void dropAnimal(GameObject animal)
    {
        int index = System.Array.IndexOf(animals, animal);

        float dist = Vector3.Distance(animal.transform.position, blackAnimals[index].transform.position);

        if (dist < 75)
        {
            animal.transform.position = blackAnimals[index].transform.position;
            source.clip = Correct[Random.Range(0, Correct.Length)];
            source.Play();
        }

        else
        {
            animal.transform.position = animalStartPos[index];
            source.clip = InCorrect;
            source.Play();
        }
    }


}
```

The console has errors:

> UnassignedReferenceException: The variable source of LevelManage has not been assigned.
>
> You probably need to assign the source variable of the LevelManage script in the inspector.

Please help!

any answers are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are the settings for your AudioSource in the inspector correct? The volume option in the inspector could be set to very low.

Comment: It sounds like you simply missed to reference one of your fields in the Inspector.. basically that's exactly what the error suggests. Please post a screenshot of your Inspector settings for the `LevelManage` component. The error you get is just a special form of a `NullReferenceException`..

Comment: Thanks @derHugo  I forgot to add it AudioSource to LevelManage

Answer (score 0):

1) Make sure your clips are imported correctly and actually play in the unity editor by selecting them in the 'Project' panel and playing like [this](https://gyazo.com/43d121d7f6eca3b7b2b775164935491c) .

2) Make sure your `source.volume` is NOT 0.

3) Make sure your `source.mute` is false.

4) Make sure your `AudioListener.volume` (the global volume) is NOT 0.

5) Make sure your `AudioListener.pause` (the global pause) is false.

6) Make sure you have 'Mute Audio' toggle in the editor not toggled this is where you can find it [image]

Comment: Thanks --Now I have this error// UnassignedReferenceException: The variable source of LevelManage has not been assigned.
You probably need to assign the source variable of the LevelManage script in the inspector.